# How to send parameter to a servlet using Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, servlets, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

i have a controller in my ExtJs application ,from where i have to make an Ajax call to a servlet and also have to send some parameters to that servlet also.i am able to call the servlet properly but i am getting null values.i think i am making mistake in sending parameters.... this is my code ...

```
dataBaseCall: function(barData){
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: "CallRatiosAnalysis",
        method:'POST',
        param:{
            source:barData
        },
        success: function(response, opts){
            //do what you want with the response here
            console.log("hiiiiiiiiiiii");
        },
        failure: function(response, opts) {
            alert("server-side failure with status code " + response.status);
        }

    });
}
```

i have to send barData to the CallRatiosAnalysis servlet. but i am getting null values in the CallRatiosAnalysis servlet .somebody please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer jeet.. It will work fine... Just replace this line....

```
url: "CallRatiosAnalysis?param="+source+"&param1="+count,
```